# 400 Bad Request when register client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, httprequest

i'm trying to sign up my parent client and even though all fields has values, I had a bad request with "please enter ... " from my server [image: as you can see my parent object is not empty in the console log but in object]

this is my schema from mongoose

```
   const parentSchema = new Schema({
  // id: { type: String },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  civil: { type: String },
  job: { type: String },
  familyMembers: { type: Number },
  demandes: { type: String },
  registerDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  child: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Child",
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});
```

> this is the parent object in react

```
{
    user: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      phone: "",
      address: {
        street: "",
        zipCode: "",
        city: "",
        state: "",
      },
      category: "parent",
    },
    civil: "",
    job: "",
    familyMembers: "",
    demandes: "",
  }
```

> my post api

```
export const postParent = async (value) => {
  try {
    await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/farah/sign-up/parent`, {
      ...value,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`postParent => ${error}`);
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**
this is my principal route

```
app.use("/farah", parentRouter);
```

this is my parent route for sign up

```
parentRouter.post(
  "/sign-up/parent",
  userValidator,
  parentValidator,
  validation,
  signup
);
```

**UPDATE : front-end error**
I tried to post a static object and it works, so the problème is not in my back-end, my nested object on front don't set values

can anyone give me hint how to set values inside nested objects react.js

Comment: Can u post your backend route where you are getting the data?

Comment: familyMembers is defined as an Number, but you pass an empty string

Comment: @bill.gates this what i'm trying to figure out, i'm not passing any empty field in my inputs but the object is readed empty in the side server